# how to get TCL ping response

Tags: linux, tcl

I have To implement ping command response, with TCL on a Linux platorm. I need to get a true or false flag in TCL depending on whether server is connected or not. Based on that I need to do some manipulation.

Any one help?

Answer (score 3):

Just [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) the regular `ping` binary and catch its error code: Unix ping returns 0, 1 or 2 depending on whether it suceeded in verifying the host's reachability of not.

You'll probablty need to use `-n N` and `-q` options to `ping` and redirect its stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

For an example on how to call an external program via `exec` and trap possible errors see the "Unix" section down in the `exec` manual page.

See also [this wiki page.](http://wiki.tcl.tk/ping)

Comment: Not really a wiki page I'd recommend, as the solution it links to has bitrotted. :-(

Comment: @DonalFellows, this link works for me http://www.networkcomputing.com/unixworld/tutorial/11.txt.html#sect2 -- not that it's really useful (the `exec` manual itself is more thorough about handling non-zero returns) but at least it's able to remove fears about running `ping` from within Tcl ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using exec probably is enough for unix systems, but you might want to use a more direct approach, eg. for use on multi-platform scripts

Digging around, the nsicmp TCL package seems to provide such ICMP ping support : https://bitbucket.org/naviserver/nsicmp/overview